# DUM and DEE differences in SQL

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I would like to know the difference between DUM and DEE. Can anybody spot the difference with real world example?

Comment: `http://flylib.com/books/en/2.214.1.38/1/` this might be helpful

Answer (score 7):

Both of them are relations that has no attributes.
A relation with no attributes can have one tuple that is "empty". So we can say:
DUM is the relation that has no attributes and no tuples. It plays the role of False.
DEE is the relation that has no attributes and a single tuple. It plays the role of True.

HTML table that represents DUM:

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```

HTML table that represents DEE:

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>
```